# Book about boy who can shapeshift?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel series (not sure how many books) in middle school so it would be 2010 or earlier. The boy, main character, had the ability to shapeshift or had some sort of magical ability. He was either an orphan or didn't have a good home life.

The biggest distinction I can remember is that there was a cat(s) that would periodically give him signs about when things were going wrong.

This description here ([Book about a boy with magic ability - shapeshifting or transformation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206655/book-about-a-boy-with-magic-ability-shapeshifting-or-transformation)) also seems familiar.

---

Books I've ruled out:

- The Switchers
- Dragon of the Lost Sea
- The Shapeshifter series

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: A much improved question

Comment: Can you offer any advice about his quest/s, other characters, the main character's name, his age, the reason for the cat to give him advice, whether there was a love interest, was the book aimed at adults or kids, was there a villain, what was the setting?

Comment: Seems unlikely, but the Children of the Red King (Charlie Bone) series has magical cats that tend to give signs, and kids with a variety of powers that include shapeshifting.